# WinRT CameraCaptureUI - no camera result

Tags: c#, camera, windows-runtime

I am trying to capture photo for my universal app, but when using `CameraCaptureUI`, there is always "Connect a camera" title in the camera UI.

I have built-in camera in my laptop, which works well. Capabilities set. I can't find even similar problem over the internet. Am I the only one who can't access camera?

My code:

```
CameraCaptureUI dialog = new CameraCaptureUI();
Size aspectRatio = new Size(16, 9);
dialog.PhotoSettings.CroppedAspectRatio = aspectRatio;
StorageFile file = await dialog.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
StorageFolder folder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;

if (file != null)
    await file.MoveAsync(folder);
```

Does anyone encountered similar issue or can advice what to try?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code isn't the problem. You need to look into your camera. Maybe it is not supported or needs a driver update or something. Using **Chrome**, go to this site and see if it picks up your cam: http://davidwalsh.name/demo/camera.php

Comment: Drivers are updated and camera works in this web test. I guess cam isn't supported then.